# Answer length threshold too high?

Tags: bug

According to [this comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19469/salary-on-unusual-job-name#comment48319_19470), this excellent answer:

> I'm not sure why you feel the need to compare. If you must, compare it
>   to other jobs that you feel sure you could land. That's the only thing
>   that is relevant anyway. If your title is to be "Director of Zerble",
>   but the only other jobs you could land are Dishwasher, or Parking Lot
>   Attendant - compare the offer to those.

...was converted into [a comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19469/salary-on-unusual-job-name#comment48312_19469), causing OP to accept [a lesser answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/19470/13535):

> It's not about the title. It's about what you'll be doing. Find out
>   what the role involves and then determine what others call it. Then
>   you can do some meaningful comparisons.
>
> You need to do more research - talk to the company and its employees
>   about what the job entails. It's not as simple as plugging a few
>   things in to an Internet search engine.

If the length threshold were a little shorter, this may have been prevented.

Comment: The OP could have chosen not to accept the answer as well... there was a choice.

Comment: @Chad, not if he wanted to mark his question answered (without waiting 24 hours!), as it was.

Comment: There is no requirement that you mark the question as answered.  There is no penalty for not choosing an answer.

Comment: @Chad, marking answered questions as such is a core feature of SE.

Comment: Only if the answer actually answers you question.  If it does not then the entire SE is better served by leaving the question with out an accepted answer.

Comment: Also the OP can choose to change the accepted answer if a better answer is posted later.  Also a core feature of SE.

Comment: @Chad, hijacking an answer like that is less preferable than asking the commenter to expand his answer (provided you know the length caused the conversion) or even waiting 24 hours to do it yourself.

Comment: There was no answer.  Joe posted a comment, then the OP asked him to make it an answer, joe deleted comment and posted expanded content answer.  Then you came here and posted this complaint about something that did not actually happen.

Comment: Because the comment was not deleted and the answer did not appear on my screen, despite the new comment not mentioning such happened appearing.

Comment: The answer was accepted before my comment was turned into an answer (at the behest of the original questioner, I believe). Seems like everything is where it should be now, right? Does it really matter which answer was accepted? It's ok if there is more than one good answer, right? (Many roads can lead to "Success")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing was converted into a comment from an answer.

The opposite happened, someone left a comment and that comment was then expanded into a non-accepted answer after being requested.

Presumably there were comments that have since been deleted that Joe had left which became part of the answer there.

Comment: After a reload, i see @JoeStrazzere had already lengthened his answer. [Current (unaccepted) answer.](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/19476/13535)

Comment: @CeesTimmerman - Actually Joe originally posted a comment, the OP asked Joe to create an answer.  Joe expanded his comment into an answer in a very productive way.  There was no need for this meta post it seems you misunderstood the situation

Comment: @Chad, then there is another bug of showing new comments but not new answers. I have the page i saw after i posted my comment as proof.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman - Then you should go report that at metaSO right away...

Comment: @Chad, [Done.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222261/new-comments-are-loaded-but-not-new-answers) Thanks.